# PDO Returned array into more accessible array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

**Information**

This should be a fairly simple question. On my website I have a post_categorys in my database that has a structure like below

```
    ID    |    Name
    1     |   Sports
    2     |   Health
    3     |   Movies
    4     |   Music
```

Now when I save a blog post I save the category_id such as `1` for `movies` in the blog_post table.

When printing out the blog post to my users I want to be able to get the blog post category name by something like `$categorys[$blog_cat_id']['name']`

Here is how I get all categorys for `$categorys` used above.

```
function getCategorysArray(){
    $STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM project_categorys');
    $STH->execute();
    return $STH->fetchAll();
}
```

But this returns the array in this format

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [name] => Sports
        [1] => Sports
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [0] => 2
        [name] => Health
        [1] => Health
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [0] => 3
        [name] => Movies
        [1] => Movies
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [0] => 4
        [name] => Music
        [1] => Music
    )
```

Therefor I am unable to use my desired method to get the category name (`$categorys[$blog_cat_id']['name']`)

**Question**

Is there a way I can remap the array somehow so that `$array[1]['name']` = `Sports` would be the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically, you want the array indexed by the value of `id`?

First, you can simplify the array by calling `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. This means you will no longer have those unnecessary `0` and `1` indexes in your returned array.

Then the simplest solution is simply to loop over the returned array.

```
$STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM project_categorys');
$STH->execute();
$results = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$ret = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $ret[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
}
return $ret;
```

Perhaps even better, we can remove the `fetchAll` call, since `PDOStatement` is `Traversable`:

```
$STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM project_categorys');
$STH->execute();

$ret = array();
foreach ($STH as $row) {
    $ret[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
}
return $ret;
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. One last question what do you mean by `Traversable`?

Comment: @Harry It means that `PDOStatement` implements [the `Traversable` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php). This means you can run `foreach` on it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function getCategorysArray(){
    $STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM project_categorys');
    $STH->execute();
    $res = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $categories = array();
    foreach($res as $row){
        $categories[$row['id']] = $row;
    }
    return $categories;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getCategories()
{
  if (null == $this->categories) {
    $stmt = $this->database->preapre('SELECT id, name FROM project_categorys')->execute();
    $categories = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach($categories as $category) {
      $this->categories[$category['id']] = $category;
    }
  }
  return $this->categories;
}
```